# How can I use the column check box and row selection function together?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ag-grid

Clicking on the checkbox selects Row.
How do I separate check box column selection from Row selection?..

Select all rows in the HeaderCheckbox table.
How do I select only the current page Row?

Please help me...

```
// colDefs
{ 
    id: 'checkbox',
    checkboxSelection: true,
    headerCheckboxSelection: true,
    headerCheckboxSelectionFilteredOnly: true,
    suppressMenu: true,
    filter: false,
    floatingFilter: false,
    suppressFilter: true,                  
    floatingFilterComponentParams: { suppressFilterButton: true },
    width: 55,
    editable: false,
}

//gridOptions
{
  ...,
  rowSelection: 'multiple',
}
```

EDIT:

The library used is: https://www.ag-grid.com/

Comment: Can you add your actual code ?

Comment: Please edit the question to have codes.

Answer (score 0):

For your first part, you can use **cellRenderer** to add a checkbox to a column and then have your own logic implemented when user selects checkbox.

```
var defaultCols = [{
        field: "Select",
        cellRenderer: chkCellRenderFunc
    },
    {
        field: "ColumnA",
        minWidth: 80
    },
    {
        field: "ColumnB",
        width: 150
    },
    {
        field: "ColumnC",
        minWidth: 80
    }
]

function chkCellRenderFunc(params) {
    var chk = document.createElement('input');
    chk.type = "checkbox";
    chk.checked = params.data.Select;
    chk.addEventListener('change', function () {
            //Add your logic for checkbox change event 
        }
        params.api.getFilterInstance('Select').resetFilterValues();
    });
return chk;
}
```